# Avoid tracing imports with sys.settrace

Tags: python, trace

Is there a way to avoid tracing all the calls that arise during an `import` statement?

I'm assuming this is due to the fact that `importlib` in my Python version (3.6.3) is written in Python, so all the calls are available to the tracer in `sys.settrace`.

Currently, tracing during an import results in ton of events, such ascalls to functions like `importlib._bootstrap`.

Comment: Do you want to skip just the importlib code, or do you want to skip the whole import statement and all code executed to perform it, including the code of the imported module?

Comment: The whole thing. I would ideally like a `line` event for the import and then nothing else. I have hacked a temporary solution which is to simply execute all the imports before any tracing (while keeping the imports in the source code to trigger `line` events)

Comment: You could probably use a combination of `dis` and `inspect` to determine whether the line you're tracing contains an import opcode, then suspend tracing until execution returns to that stack frame.

Comment: That's a solid idea. When you say suspend tracing, do you mean actually set/return a new tracing function, or continue with the same function and just check until the stack frame provided to the tracing function matches the one that I had when I suspended? I'm fairly new to using sys tracing, so apologies if this should be clear to me.

Comment: Check the stack frame until you return to the one that issued the import call, and have the global trace function return `None` to specify no local trace function for scopes entered in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a "faster" way? I.e. a way to default to no tracing (so not even checks on calls) until I return to that original frame? I am planning on doing this broadly for any non-user code that executes so removing that overhead would be great

Comment: I don't know a faster way.